# Order multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Im looking to order the following array by the "timestamp" section of the array from lowest to highest (ASC).

```
Array
(
[188] => Array
    (
        [date] => 28-04-2012
        [timestamp] => 1335571200
        [opposition] => Rayleigh 1st XI
        [teaperson] => 
    )

[182] => Array
    (
        [date] => 08-03-2012
        [timestamp] => 1331164800
        [opposition] => Galleywood 1st XI
        [teaperson] => 33
    )

[180] => Array
    (
        [date] => 07-07-2012
        [timestamp] => 1341619200
        [opposition] => High Roding 1st XI
        [teaperson] => 45
    )

)
```

I have seen the array_multisort function but unsure of how to use it correctly.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`usort`](http://php.net/usort)

```
usort($arr,function($a,$b) {return $a['timestamp']-$b['timestamp'];})
```